# Insert column value from another table referenced as foreign key in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework-5

i have two tables.Once is for storing user information and second one is for storing images related to that user.

```
tblUser-->pkUserId
tblPictues-->pkPicId and fkUserId.
```

how can i add a new user and then save pkUserId in tblPictures using entity.saveChanges() only once at end(After adding records to both tables).

```
 _objEntites.tblUser.Add(_objtblUser);
var pkUser_Id = _objtblUser.pkUserId;
```

It is givnig me `00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000`.

Comment: If you have foreign key in the database entity framework should be able to save them through the relationship properties. And pkUserId won't be available until you call SaveChanges. Why do you need to access pkUserId anyways?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you haven't told Entity Framework that your ID is auto-generated. Add the following to your EF class:

```
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
public Guid pkUserId { get; set; }
```

Comment: Thanks mattytommo. I am new to EF .So can you please tell me where to add above code? i have Entity.context.cs in EF.Should i add there ?

Comment: @Gerry No problems, you need to add that attribute to your `pkUserId` field in your EF `tblUser` class.